# How to set a specific time's timezone to a specific timezone and ignore the browser's timezone with momentjs?

Tags: timezone, momentjs

I have momentjs and moment-timezone.

For example I have this string as my time:

```
var myTime = "11/20/2016 8:15 PM";
```

Now I want to tell momentjs that "myTime" is in "Europe/Moscow" timezone which is UTC+3 (ignoring my browser's timezone which is UTC+3:30).

Then I want to change the time to UTC.

So I want "myTime" to be `20-11-2016 20:15:00+3:00`

And When I change it to utc(), I want it to give me `20-11-2016 17:15:00`

What I did was this:

First I set the default timezone: `moment.tz.setDefault('Europe/Moscow');`

Then I did this:

```
moment("11/20/2016 8:15 PM").utc().format()
```

What momentjs did with this code was this: `2016-11-20T16:45:00+00:00`

Why? Because it first checked my browser's timezone which is UTC+3:30. Changed "myTime" to the Europe/Moscow timezone so `moment("11/20/2016 8:15 PM").format()` will return `"2016-11-20T19:45:00+03:00"` (it subtracted 30 minutes from myTime) then changed it to UTC which resulted `2016-11-20T16:45:00+00:00`

So my question is this:

How can I set a timezone for `11/20/2016 8:15 PM` ignoring browser's timezone and then change it to UTC.

If my question is still unclear, please let me know so I give more info.

Comment: You have to use [moment parsing specifying format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) when using string not in ISO 8601 format. So use `moment("11/20/2016 8:15 PM", 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A')` instead of `moment("11/20/2016 8:15 PM")`. Maybe adding a snippet or a fiddle showing your issue can clarify further your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the timezone when you create the moment object, like that:

```js
var myTime = moment.tz('11/20/2016 8:15 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A', 'Europe/Moscow');
var utcTime = myTime.clone().utc();

console.log('myTime', myTime.format());
console.log('utcTime', utcTime.format());
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

The 2 `console.log()` print:

```
myTime 2016-11-20T20:15:00+03:00
utcTime 2016-11-20T17:15:00Z
```

With `utcTime` which is 3 hours before `myTime`.

Comment: Is the first one still working ? I get a deprecated warning and an inconsistent value

Comment: created a question for the same. Please help  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55945940/momentjs-how-to-convert-a-time-in-a-specific-timezone-and-certain-format-into-m