# MomentJS: How To convert a time in a specific timezone and certain format into milliseconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have a time "2000" in format "hhmm" for certain timezone say 'Asia/Kolkata'.
Tried a couple of approaches mentioned in other answers but none are giving the right answers.

***Expected*** : Exact time in local timezone (8pm in Asia/Kolkata)

This is being run server side in NodeJs not a browser .

**Tried these methods :**

```
let localTime1 = moment('2000').tz('Asia/Kolkata');
let localTime2 = moment('2000','hhmm').tz('Asia/Kolkata');
let localTime3 = moment('2000', 'hhmm', 'Asia/Kolkata');
```

Both give a value 1556827200000 which is 1:30 pm in local timezone and 8 pm in UTC .

***What I need is 8pm in local time zone.***

I also get a warning as below :

```
Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO 
format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable             
across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are 
discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to 
http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: 
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 
2000, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
Error
at Function.createFromInputFallback (/user_code/node_modules/moment-timezone/node_modules/moment/moment.js:320:98)
at configFromString (/user_code/node_modules/moment-timezone/node_modules/moment/moment.js:2385:15)
at configFromInput (/user_code/node_modules/moment-timezone/node_modules/moment/moment.js:2611:13)
at prepareConfig
```

Any help in the right direction would be helpful. Thanks !

Comment: did you tried my answer bro?

Comment: It should give 8 pm in IST but it gives 8pm in UTC when i run in node server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To parse `'2000'` as `8:00pm` use: `'HHmm'` (As noted in the [Moment docs on parsing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), the parsing tokens are case-sensitive. `'hh'` is for 12 hour time formats)
2. To parse a date/time into a particular timezone use the [`moment.tz(..., String);` function](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/).

This will give you "8:00pm in the Asia/Kolkata timezone", rather than "8:00pm UTC *converted* to Asia/Kolkata timezone".

Putting it all together:

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

let localTime1 = moment.tz('2000', 'HHmm', 'Asia/Kolkata')

console.log(localTime1.toString());
// 'Thu May 02 2019 20:00:00 GMT+0530'
```

Of course you can use Moment's formatting functions out output the date/time in whatever format you need :)

Answer (score -1):

**Try this,** Hopefully usefull  :

```
moment('2000','hh:mm').tz('Asia/Kolkata').format('hh:mm');
```

or else, try on below link: 
copy below code and paste into javascript area and see the 3rd line of output.

```
$('#divThai').text(moment('2000','hh:mm').tz('Asia/Kolkata').format('hh:mm'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uq99udc9/4/

Comment: It works fine! Upvote to answer and accept this answer buddy!.

Comment: Hey , Just tried it  : it doesn't give as intended . This is node server and it is giving back the same in UTC format

Comment: bro you can try here, on jsfiddle then it is working fine